# How to make a download link to a Youtube video in MP3?

Tags: python, download, youtube, mp3

I am doing a service that requires a way to download the mp3 of choice from Youtube. I want them to input the youtube URL and for the program to create a download link that downloads the mp3 file

Comment: have you looked at youtube-dl?

Answer (score 1):

I would consider looking into the [pytube](https://github.com/pytube/pytube) library which seems to do a great deal of what you're wanting:

```
from pytube import YouTube
import os
  
yt = YouTube('https://Youtube-URL.com')
 
# extract audio
video = yt.streams.filter(only_audio=True).first() 
 
# download the MP3
out_file = video.download(output_path='your/dir/here') 
  
# save the file
base, ext = os.path.splitext(out_file)
new_MP3_file = base + '.mp3'
os.rename(out_file, new_MP3_file)
```

Comment: Ok yeah that answers most of my question but I need it to give a link to download

Comment: This downloads it to your computer to some given path. I'd need more information about your use-case to understand how you'd need a link set up

Comment: ok, so I'm making a discord bot and users could give a command with a URL, it would then give them a URL back that would send them to a website that downloads it to their device. I know I probably need javascript for this so can you help me with that cuz I'm not very good at it

Comment: you need more than javascript, for that you'd have to host your own server, which runs the script I posted, and then allows a user to download it from there. Would be just as easy to send the user to a third party website that already does this like https://ytmp3.cc/7a63b/

Comment: Oh, thanks! will probably do that